# Drupal Commerce Packaging deposit

Tags: commerce

Some products are delivered on a pallet and customers need to pay a deposit for those.

1 to 26 products go on 1 pallet. I need a rule that adds 1 pallet to the shopping card when the amount of that product is between 1 and 26.

For every 26 products more added to the shopping card there has to be added 1 pallet to the shopping card.

I created a rule that works fine when 1 to 26 products are added. But when customers add ore then 26 products to there card it does not work.

This is the rule I currently have:

```
{ "rules_sn_pallet_siniat_statiegeld_1_26" : { 
    "LABEL" : "SN Pallet Siniat statiegeld 1-26",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "pallet" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ 
      "commerce_rules_extra",
      "commerce_conditions",
      "commerce_order",
      "commerce_cart"
    ],  
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
    "IF" : [ 
      { "commerce_rules_extra_rules_condition_has_term" : { 
          "line_item" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0" ],
          "field_name" : "field_soort_pallet",
          "term_id" : "122"
        }   
      },  
      { "AND" : [ 
          { "commerce_conditions_compare_total_product_type_quantity" : { 
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
              "product_type" : "product",
              "exclude" : 0,
              "operator" : "=",
              "value" : "1" 
            }   
          }   
        ]   
      },  
      { "AND" : [ 
          { "commerce_order_compare_total_product_quantity" : { 
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
              "operator" : "\u003C=",
              "value" : "26"
            }   
          }   
        ]   
      }   
    ],  
    "DO" : [ 
      { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : { 
          "USING" : { 
            "user" : [ "commerce-order:owner" ],
            "sku" : "100",
            "quantity" : "1",
            "combine" : 1 
          },  
          "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Productfactuurregel toegevoegd" } } 
        }   
      }   
    ]   
  }   
}
```

Comment: There's still not actually a question in there. :)
We can't tell you what's wrong with a set of rules we can't see.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Inlined the rule so the question doesn't depend on an external file. Voted to reopen.